# spark 1.6 with akka within same application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

I'm working on one application which involved some ETL jobs which I'm trying to implement with spark 1.6. And also some web server which I've implemented with akka http. Both pieces work fine separately but when I move it in single app - spark start to fail with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter;
at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:33)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:28)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:39)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:39)
at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:39)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree1$1(ActorSystem.scala:795)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:788)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:246)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:289)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:264)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:2024)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2015)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:457)
```

This is my dependencies:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.2",
"com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.19",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.19",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.3",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.1.3"
```

Sample code:

```
object AppStarter {  

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) // FAIL happens here
  }

}
```

I was trying to play around `akka-native` version settings but it doesn't help but I've got different error each time. Is there any way to force spark to ignore akka dependencies in the same scope?

Comment: Spark 1.6 depends on Akka 2.3.

Comment: makes sense, let me check

Answer (score -2):

it look like you want to use spark Sql, for this prefer the usage of `SparkSession.builder`

```
SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[4]")
  .appName("Spark recommendation")
  .getOrCreate()
```

You can have a look at the documentation here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

With this you can pass more configuration parameters using :
`.config("spark.executor.memory", "4g")` for example.

Comment: does SparkSession supported only started spark 2+ ? I'm using spark 1.6. And I guess your answer actually doesn't address question problem.